# indexOf not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var myurl = window.location;
    var pos = myurl.IndexOf("memberId");
    if (pos = -1) {
        alert("false");
    } else {
        alert("true");
     }
```

For some reason I can't seem to get this simple method to work. Chrome says 'myurl does not contain the method 'indexOf''. Any reason?

Comment: `if (pos = -1)` shouldn't that be `if (pos == -1)`?

Comment: `window.location` is an object. Objects don't own the `indexOf` method. Even if you have a typo there, it wouldn't work either way.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe typo but it should be

```
myurl.indexOf
```

lowercase `i`.

And [`location` is an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location), so you want:

```
var myurl = window.location.href;
```

*(and all the other things people say in the comments and other answers ;))*

**Update:** To see what kind of properties an object has, just type, in this case, `window.location` in the console:

[image: Chrome console]

Answer (score 3):

`window.location` returns an object. Perhaps you wanted `window.location.pathname`? :-)

There's also a problem with this line:

```
if (pos = -1)
```

It should be

```
if (pos == -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

try `var myurl = window.location.pathname;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var myurl = window.location.toString();
```